# Visual Studio multiple projects C# and C++ documentation

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, documentation, doxygen

I have a Visual Studio 2013 Solution with multiple projects (C++, C#). So I have different comment styles in the C# files I'm using the XML style.

```
/// <summary>
/// Comment
/// </summary>
```

In the C++ files I'm using these comments.

```
/*Comment*/
```

Now I tried to create a documentation with doxygen of all projects with the different comment style but it didn't worked.

I also tried to use the XML comments in the C++ files and to parse it but it only recognized the C# files.

How can I create one documentation of the two comment styles?

or

How can I create a documentation of C# and C++ files with the XML comment style?

Comment: You're saying that the C# style comments ins't working in C++?

Comment: Did you use `/* Comment */` for doc comments in C++ or `/** comment */`? Because only the latter will be recognized, as written in  the [doxygen manual](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/docblocks.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **GhostDoc**, **Sandcastle**, **docu**, **nocco**, **natural docs**, **document! x**

Answer (score 2):

[GhostDoc](http://submain.com/ghostdoc) may be useful, it is a very nice documentation tool for .NET codes